# How to make zval from HashTable

Tags: php, php-extension

How to make `zval` from `HashTable`.
I have `HashTable`. But needs `zval` to use with `call_user_function`.

Comment: `zval = HashTable + 2`

Comment: What code do you have? What is the context of this question? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What code do you have? What is the context of this question? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ZVAL_ARR` macro will do this for you.

Given `HashTable *ht`,

```
zval arr;
ZVAL_ARR(&arr, ht);
```

`arr` is now an array that wraps `ht`.